# how to get foreign key table field by name

Tags: python, django

throught this i am getting all the data fro the database

```
context['table1'] = table1.objects.filter(user_id = hos_id).filter(type = 1).filter(status = 1)
```

Models I have

```
class table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Active'),
        (0, 'Inactive'),
        (2, 'Deleted'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(
        _('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)



class table1(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField()
    vc = models.ForeignKey(table2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    v_no = models.CharField(max_length=25,unique=True)
    dist = models.CharField(max_length=11,blank=False,null=False)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'user1'),
        (2, 'user2'),
```

> Through above query i am getting multiple records every record have
>   their vc which i am getting the primary key of vc i want the category name for the every record isntead of id
>   relation of model is already given.

please help me related to this i am facing this. how can i get thename fromthe single query with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a str function to vehicle model

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle_category.category_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Vehicle_list = Vehicle.objects.filter(user_id = hospital_id).filter(user_type = 
1).filter(status = 1)

context = {}
for item in Vehicle_list:
    context[item.user_id] = item.vehicle_category.category_name
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.